# How to Migrate data from my mongodb Database from mlab to dynamoDb using AWS-DMS

Tags: aws-dms

i want to migrate data from my mongodb databse which is in mlab to dynamodb using AWS-DMS service , how to do it..??

i created a souce and target endpoints , after that i dont know what to do

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this. this gives clear steps to do migration. it also includes tips for shard(mongo).
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/performing-a-live-migration-from-a-mongodb-cluster-to-amazon-dynamodb/

Comment: Please add relevant sections of the answer here itself as links might change over time.